# Como executar html em uma activity?

Tags: android

Como faço para que minha aplicação execute um arquivo html salvo em uma pasta dentro do aplicativo?

Comment: como assim executar? voce fala abrir a pagina num espaço determinado por exemplo? se sim basta usar um webview

Comment: mais o webview , consigo executar ele apartir de um arquivo ? ou é só via link de sites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta abrir o arquivo em uma [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

Adicione a `WebView` eu seu arquivo de layout:

```
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/webview"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

E em sua `Activity` você carrega o conteúdo do arquivo, desta forma:

```
setContentView(R.layout.my);
    WebView mWebView = null;
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/new.html"); //local do arquivo .html
```

Caso queira outros exemplos, você pode [olhar esta pergunta.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4027701/4843158)